# python3 -- getting POST request text from requests.post?

Tags: python-3.x, post, request

I'm using python3. For debugging purposes, I'd like to get the exact text that is sent to the remote server via a `requests.post` command. The `requests.post` object seems to contain the response text, but I'm looking for the request text.

For example ...

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = json.dumps({'abc':'def','ghi':'jkl'})
url = 'http://example.com/site.php'
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

How do I get the text of the exact request that is sent to `url` via this POST command?

Comment: Just to note you can just pass a Python dictionary to `data=` and it'll all work out just fine...

Comment: Anyway - is `r.request.body` what you're after?

Comment: `r.request.body` just returns the JSON string I sent. I'd like all of the actual data that is sent via the HTTP dialog, if possible. Also, I do my own JSON conversion, because in the real world, I use a custom JSONEncoder.

Comment: Right... the headers are strangely in `r.request.headers` and so on... or are you after the actual physical data sent as one large byte string or something?

Comment: Yes, I want the physical data, if possible. I know I can reconstruct it via `r.request.headers`, `r.request.body`, and possibly other attributes. But I might miss something. For debugging purposes, I want to see __exactly__ what is being sent over the net, if I can.